# Cannot kill the process and start the same process using script

Tags: bash

I am trying to kill a process and start the same process.

When I kill the process using `pkill` on the command-line and start the service using `nsd`, it works just fine. But when I use the same command in my script it shows following errors:

> nsd[18652]: notice: nsd starting (NSD 4.1.15)
>
> nsd[18652]: error: can't bind udp socket: Address already in use
>
> nsd[18652]: error: server initialization failed, nsd could not be
>   started
>
> error: connect (127.0.0.1@8952): Connection refused

**script.sh contains**

```
pkill nsd

nsd

nsd-control reload
```

Comment: I think your process is not being killed. And The error `Address already in use` suggests that the port of the server is already being used by some other  process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pkill nsd

# wait until nsd has disappeared
while pgrep nsd; do sleep 1; done

nsd
nsd-control reload
```